# DataAdapter.Update() and its use of the dataset relationship schema

Tags: ado.net, dataset, dataadapter

I have a dataset with multiple tables and the necessary relations in place to call SQL statements in the proper order.

When the Adapter.Update() method is called, I presume it scours the relationships between all tables to determine the order in which it makes SQL calls.

For example:

- A delete in Table A requires first a delete in Table B.
- An insert in Table B first requires an insert into Table A.

How can I leverage the mechanism it uses to implement my own update strategy?

Reason being, rather than being able to allow the Adapter to perform the Updates, I instead need to call Stored Procedures.

*** * * * * * EDIT * * * * * ***

The dataSet is passed from the UI client to a back-end server component.
On the back end server, the DataAdapter.Update(dataSet) occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the RowUpdating Event on your Tables and call your Stored Procedure from there ... also set SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs.Status to SkipCurrentRow to prevent the standard Update Sql Command from being triggered and call SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs.Row.AcceptChanges() to set the RowState back to Unchanged ...

Comment: Thank you kindly - I'm exploring this suggestion.  However, I have multiple tables and the DataAdapter decides what to do and when.  Seems rather than focusing at the granular table level, instead to intercept commands carried out by the DataAdapter.  Does your suggestion take that into consideration?

Comment: That is, rather than DataAdpater.Update(table), I'm doing DataAdapter.Update(dataSet).

Comment: That's the point ... hopefully ... you call Update on the Dataset and the Framework triggers the RowUpdating Event for your Tables in the correct order ... but I have to admit that I didn't verify it actually works like that ...

Comment: thanks again - I did some light tests and seems those events kick off when the tables are modified.  I need something to hook into the Update and fires on each row it processes.  I'll however keep working per your suggestion to see if perhaps it can still be utilized.

Comment: Hey wait! The DataAdapter also has a "RowUpdating" property!!! I'll see what that buys me!!!

Comment: You're right ... I have to apologize ... the RowUpdating Event is on the Adapter ...